# What NEMA configuration is this receptacle?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

This looks like a type H-39, but I can't tell if it's 125V, or 250V. A coworker sent the picture and they didn't test for voltage. Is there anyway to tell what kind it is without testing it? Is it even an H-39?

[image: Receptacle]

[image]

Comment: Could you get a better picture? That image is so dark and blurry that it is hard to make out the socket. But it looks closest to the H-39 (outward tab and longer hole next to it.)

Comment: that matches rows 1 & 2

Comment: This is the only picture he took. I agree that it matches rows 1 & 2, but I was wondering if there was a way to determine if it's 250V or 125V without testing with a DMM. I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: What is the diameter of the outlet , I have some of these at my plant same pinout with both 125 /250v amperages 20-50 range. If in a residence I would be expecting 240v, if in a older business it could be low voltage 3 phase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From everything I can find 1 and 2 are the same receptacle. It's just a matter of application
[image]

[image]

So in answer to your question **NO**. you need to test it to find out it's apllication.

Sorry I couldn't be of any help.

Comment: That's what I was thinking was the answer too. Thank's for the help!